# Modify HTML content during Web Scraping

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to do some Web Scraping

The objective is to collect all remedials according to the postal code. The problem is when I try my code, my list is empty because the url did't change according to the postal code. This is why I want to change the HTML value during the scrape.

I'm not sure how to do this. I tried using `Selenium` and `XPATH` however I wasn't able to find anything.

Here's the HTML Code: (in red is what I need to change.)

EDIT :  Indeed, the goal is to collect the pagination with the name and the type of remedial according to the postal code, this is why I want to change the HTML content during the scrap.

This is the best that I can do for the moment, I hope u will see the error

Comment: Hi, you need to include relevant code. What have you tried? Also nobody here knows how to use that page which is not in English. Let's say I click on the first link you provided and then click on *"Spécialistes du vitrage"*, enter French post code 75020 and press search button. I can see a result list with pagination. Is that what you want? Well, if so, Selenium should be able to get it no matter if URL doesn't change. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

This input is in a form, which is good because `Selenium` has special functionalities to handle forms.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.maif.fr/services-en-ligne/consultationreparateurs/geolocaliserReparateur.action?view"
query = "whatever you want to put into the search box"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
webform_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='adresseInternaute']")
webform_input.send_keys(query)
webform_input.submit()
```

The key here is `submit()`. It will walk the HTML tree until it finds a button within the current form, meaning you don't have to write an extra two lines just to click the search button.